# Response of a Differential Pair to Differential Mode Signals

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, circuit-design, signal, differential

I do not understand this kind of analysis of a Mosfet Differential Pair:

[image]

This analysis wants to prove that, when a purely differential mode signal is applied (so opposite signals are applied between the transistor gates and GND), it is possible to analyze only half of the circuit, with GND at the point E, as shown in the following picture.

The statement I read is that since V1 = - V2, the potential at point E should be equal and opposite to itself (**first question**: why? Is it due to the symmetric voltage drops between the gate and the source of the 2 MOSFETs?) and this is possible only if it is constant in time, and so it is put equal to GND (**first question**: what does it mean? A constant voltage is not necessarily equal to GND).

Can you explain me this procedure step by step?

**Third question**: with differential signals, can be both Mosfet ON?

Comment: `The statement I read is that since V1 = - V2, the potential at point E should be equal and opposite to itself ` -- Would be useful if you put the reference to this statement.

Comment: RE: "A constant voltage is not necessarily equal to GND"; in AC analysis it is.

Comment: There needs to be both common mode (CM) bias and a differential mode (DM) signal  for this to work. Then they share the current in Re and the difference is seen in R1 or R2 . For better reading choose from here https://duckduckgo.com/?q=differential+fet+amp+analysis&t=palemoon&ia=web